# How to find a specific code source using dev tools and then find it in FTTP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm quite new in programming, so I encounter a lot of problems. For example I am editing a WordPress theme and I use inspect element to determine what kind of HTML code needs to go, but then I always struggle to find the specific location of a file (using FTP) where the code sits for me to edit it or add something new. Can some one please help me understand how can I achieve some thing like that? Because it is such a drag to open every .php file and ctrl+f in hope of finding the specific line. It seems so easy to work with CSS but when it comes to HTML I always can't find what I am looking for.

Comment: Any modern code editor can search across all the files in a directory. Download the whole directory and search against it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, you can use the grep command. It will search in all of the files which you specify. Another option is to use it via SSH to your hosting account. For example:

```
grep -irl "string" ./
```

Chrome and Mozilla's developer tool is showing in which file is the element. For example, click on Inspect in Mozilla --> Styles --> In the right column you will see the style (CSS) and you can check the file. If you check this website's style the body class is in all.css file.

Hope this helps you.